# Elastic Search: simple query not returning expected results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.2.0 but this also happens in 1.x versions.

One of the text fields contains the word google.com. When I try to search google, ElasticSearch doesn't return anything. But if I search google.com it returns the document that contains it.

My query is simple, something like this:

```
query: {
  filtered: {
    query: {
      simple_query_string: {
        query: "google"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What should I do to make Elastic search return the document when i search for google?

Comment: did you try with a wildcard query ?

Comment: @AlainIb google*? Yes, in this case it returns the document that I want + a lot of other documents that aren't fully related to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#mapping-all-field) about the `_all` field, because the `simple_query_string` uses this field when none are specified, which is your case.

`_all` is indexed by default with the `standard` analyzer, which means that `google.com` will not be split at `.` and will be indexed as `google.com`. Which means that searching for `google.com` will look for this term in your index whereas in your text you have `google`.

Searching in Elasticsearch is not only about the query, **but also about the way you index the data**. It may not be as simple as *SQL query with LIKE* but at the same time, ES gives you way more power at *insert* time than SQL.

Depending on what you want from your `simple_query` you have multiple options to choose from:

- change the analyzer of `_all` field:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "letter": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "letter",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "_all": {
        "analyzer": "letter"
      }
```

and the query:

```
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "google"
    }
  }
```

- change the analyzer of your `field` and **use that field in `query_string_query`:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "letter": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "letter",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "letter"
        }
      }
```

And the query:

```
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "google",
      "fields": ["text"]
    }
  }
```

- define your own [custom _all field with your own `letter` analyzer and use that in simple_query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#custom-all-fields)

Answer (score 0):

I do this kind of query with "wildcard" query

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "wildcard": {
          "fieldname": "google*" // replace the fieldname her
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm exposing simple_query to my users since sometimes they use things like "term1 -term2". Isn't it possible to adjust simple_query to return the results by only searching for google? It looks like something simple since a SQL query with LIKE would return this result ( which is pretty obvious ).